# Regular Expression for accurate word-count using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, word-count

I'm trying to put together a regular expression for a JavaScript command that accurately counts the number of words in a textarea.

One solution I had found is as follows:

```
document.querySelector("#wordcount").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#editor").value.split(/\b\w+\b/).length -1;
```

But this doesn't count any non-Latin characters (eg: Cyrillic, Hangul, etc); it skips over them completely.

Another one I put together:

```
document.querySelector("#wordcount").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#editor").value.split(/\s+/g).length -1;
```

But this doesn't count accurately unless the document ends in a space character. If a space character is appended to the value being counted it counts 1 word even with an empty document. Furthermore, if the document begins with a space character an extraneous word is counted.

Is there a regular expression I can put into this command that counts the words accurately, regardless of input method?

Comment: Off-topic, but `document.querySelector("#wordcount")` can be written `document.getElementById("wordcount")`, which may be either more compatible cross-browser or faster; it's unlikely to be less compatible or slower.

Comment: An accurate definition of the term "word" is missing.

Comment: @Tomalak, missing in general, or missing in the question? ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This should do what you're after:

```
value.match(/\S+/g).length;
```

Rather than splitting the string, you're matching on any sequence of non-whitespace characters.

There's the added bonus of being easily able to extract each word if needed ;)

Comment: Thanks. One question though. Using match rather than split returns null when there are no words, even if there are space characters. I can use an if/else command to resolve this, but is there a better way?

Comment: I wonder how the OP feels about having `you-and-I` treated as one word, or `you & I` treated as three words or `you - and I` treated as four words.

Comment: @Haidon if you store the return value from `.match()` in `var words` then `length = words && words.length || 0`

Comment: Hi, Do anybody know regex for   "32 43.43 ..." (60 number seperated by space) ? thanks

Comment: +1 Thank you as it works however, I would request you please change yours to value.match(/\b\S+\b/g).length   as it doesn't count punctuation. For example using  /\S+/g counts the "?" given a space before it as a word which you wouldn't want.

Answer (score 7):

Try to count anything that is not whitespace and with a word boundary:

```
value.split(/\b\S+\b/g).length
```

You could also try to use unicode ranges, but I am not sure if the following one is complete:

```
value.split(/[\u0080-\uFFFF\w]+/g).length
```

Comment: `value.split` is the wrong way to go, but if you instead do `(value.match(/\b\S+\b/g) || []).length` this works pretty well.  I found Phrogz's examples on the accepted answer a helpful test; this gives: `count("you-and-I")==1`, `count("you & I")==2`, `count("you - and I")==3`, `count("Phrogz's examples")==2`.  The only questionable one is `you-and-I` but this construction is rare enough that extra complexity probably isn't worth it, especially to make sure you get possessives correct.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
    value.match(/\w+/g).length;
```

This will match a string of characters that can be in a word. Whereas something like:

```
    value.match(/\S+/g).length;
```

will result in an incorrect count if the user adds commas or other punctuation  that is not followed by a space - or adds a comma with a space either side of it.

Answer (score 4):

For me this gave the best results:

```
value.split(/\b\W+\b/).length
```

with

```
var words = value.split(/\b\W+\b/)
```

you get all words.

Explanation:

- \b is a word boundary
- \W is a NON-word character, capital usually means the negation
- '+' means 1 or more characters or the prefixed character class

I recommend learning regular expressions. It's a great skill to have because they are so powerful. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you could extend/change you methods like this

`document.querySelector("#wordcount").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#editor").value.split(/\b\(.*?)\b/).length -1;` if you want to match things like email-addresses as well

and

`document.querySelector("#wordcount").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#editor").value.trim().split(/\s+/g).length -1;`

also try using `\s` as its the `\w` for unicode

source:http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 1):

The correct regexp would be `/s+/` in order to discard non-words:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor , sit amet'.split(/\S+/g).length
7
'Lorem ipsum dolor , sit amet'.split(/\s+/g).length
6
```

Comment: You really think that a comma should be counted as a word?

Comment: `'   ,    ,     ,   ,   '` has 5 words according to your solution :D

Comment: Not accurate, sorry

Answer (score 0):

my **simple** JavaScript library, called FuncJS has a function called "count()" which does exactly what it's called — count words.

For example, say that you have a string full of words, you can simply place it in between the function brackets, like this:

```
count("How many words are in this string?");
```

and then call the function, which will then return the number of words. Also, this function is designed to ignore any amount of whitespace, thus giving an accurate result.

To learn more about this function, please read the documentation at http://docs.funcjs.webege.com/count().html and the download link for FuncJS is also on the page.

Hope this helps anyone wanting to do this! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const wordsCount = str.match(/\p{L}+/gu).length
```

Comment: This might be a better answer than some others already here, but it would really help to explain what `\p{L}` does and why it solves the problem better.

Comment: `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language

Comment: \p - special point. It works when we adds flag /u (means unicode).
{L} - category, L - means Letters
So \p{L} means any letter from any unicode alphabet. It excludes numbers and  special characters