# Jquery word counter without maximum number

Tags: jquery, plugins, word-count

Could you suggest any word counter in jquery which doesn't have `maxcount` option ?

I have looked for many plugins but all of them limits the maximum word number.

I would like to have a function which takes two parameters, `textarea_id` and `span_id_of_#ofwords` and just simply show the numbers of the words in textarea.I may modify the plugins but I rather not to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593565/regular-expression-for-accurate-word-count-using-javascript). With that you can do:

```
function countWords(textarea_id, span_id)
{
   $("#"+span_id).text($("#"+textarea_id).val().match(/\S+/g).length)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, why can't you just count it yourself? it'd be something like:

```
$(#span_id_of_NoOfwords).html($(#textarea_id).text().split(' ').length))?
```