# How to find the number of words in string - JAVA

Tags: java, string, loops

How can to find the number of words in string without using loops in Java?

Comment: Can you define words in your context?

Comment: by "words", did you mean "letters"?

Comment: I think this is pointless since soon or latter in some code there will be a loop over the words. I would recommend you to implement it yourself using the most efficient way you can thought and it will be fine (:

Comment: is this an interview question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. There are definitely no loops here (assuming `String.length` does not iterate and `String.substring` does not make a copy), not even behind the scenes, except in the printing of course.

```
  static int nSpaces ( String s ) {
    int n = 0;
    if ( s.length() > 0 ) {
      if ( s.length() > 1 ) {
        // Split it in half.
        int center = s.length() / 2;
        // Count each half.
        n += nSpaces(s.substring(0, center))
           + nSpaces(s.substring(center));
      } else {
        // Just 1 character.
        if ( s.charAt(0) == ' ' ) {
          // It's a space.
          n += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    //System.out.println(n+" spaces in '"+s+"'");
    return n;
  }

  static int nWords ( String s ) {
    return nSpaces (s) + 1;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party.";
    System.out.println("nWords(\""+test+"\") = "+nWords(test));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid loops, you'll have to use recursion.

Comment: I can't to use the recursion.

Comment: why can't you use recursion...?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
int words = new java.util.StringTokenizer(myString," ").countTokens();
```

Haven't tried if it works, but should.

Comment: @user1763031 See edit, made a fatal syntax mistake. Reconsider accepting my answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1)  You can use `split`, and then get the length of the resulting array, but this will count anything that is not whitespace (e.g. numbers) as words
2)  [Use a regex to match anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593565/regular-expression-for-accurate-word-count-using-javascript) (you can tweak anything) between whitespace.

Comment: split() uses a for loop?

Comment: I don't know if it does internally, but to count the number of tokens, you don't need to loop....

Comment: i don't think that matters.  I mean, the assembly is going to use gotos whether or not there are loops....

Answer (score 0):

1. You can split the string to get all the words.
2. Apply a filter/regex to remove unnecessary punctuation, chars,etc.
3. Then put the complete array in a set to get the unique words.

At each above step you can get the answer you are looking for deppednign how your requirements wants words(unique or duplciate)