# Need a recursive function to work on arrays

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need to write code for a recursive function, which actually operates on an array and divides the array in two new arrays, of unequal size based on certain condition, (say, using condition function X). After that the the function keeps on operating on each of the newly created arrays until the arrays contain only one element each. Can you help me with a code that actually can do this. I am giving a rough idea about what I need to do.  :

```
recursive_function func1 (array) {
    conditional_function X();
    creates, array1[] and array2[]
    perform the same on each of array1 and array2
    until all arr
}
```

Comment: You'll want to use `Arrays.copyOf` to split the array.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Creating the "condition function" or to recurse? Is it really necessary to use to newly created arrays or can you operate "in place". There are so many ways to do it, that we need a little more info.

Comment: what is that *certain condition*

Comment: What shall be the return value of your recursive function? Have you come up with some own ideas?

Comment: Try writing an implementation, and get back with a question regarding what you have problems with. In the current formulation, the question looks like an assignment a teacher gave you for a programming course, which is just copied to Stackoverflow in order to get someone else to solve the problem. Stackoverflow will not implement the code for such a question, but could help you solve problems which you run into while you are implementing the code.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13315123/823393) is an example that counts words in a string recursively. You may find it useful as an example to start with.

Comment: @Alderath, and all,:   well, it's not an assignment. it's in fact a part of a bigger program that I am working on. Actually at this part, I am just not able to think of a better option other than choosing a recursive function. but in order to do that I am facing the problem, how to deal with the array, that's it. I will just try out the approach given by, 'Arun P Johny' and let you know later. thank you anyway.

Comment: @Fildor, my problem is with creating the recurse. And yes, it is not necessary to create two arrays. The idea is, the condition function divides the array elements in two groups and I need to keep this thing going until all formed groups contain just one element each.  You can consider a tree structure.

Comment: You don't need a tree structure, you need indexes. Like `recurse( array, int start, int length ). So you would start with index 0 and full array length. In the recursion there would be to calls: 1. recurse( array, 0, somelengthX ) and recurse( array, X, remainingLength) and so on, until length is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to do this

Ex:

```
import com.greytip.common.utils.StringUtils;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] array = new Object[11];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = i;

        }
        recursive(array);
    }

    private static void recursive(Object[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("return: " + StringUtils.join(array));
            return;
        }

        int pos = x(array);

        Object[] part1 = new Object[pos];
        Object[] part2 = new Object[array.length - pos];
        System.out.println("array : " + StringUtils.join(array)
                + ", part1: 0.." + pos + ", part2: " + part1.length + ".."
                + part2.length);

        System.arraycopy(array, 0, part1, 0, part1.length);
        System.arraycopy(array, part1.length, part2, 0, part2.length);

        recursive(part1);
        recursive(part2);

    }

    private static int x(Object[] array) {
        return array.length / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, this code really helped. Problem is solved now.

Comment: @AnirbanDas Please share your solution, and if this solution solved the problem the mark it as accepted

Comment: I am really sorry to say that I have restrictions to put the code here. All I can say is that your code clarified my concept and that actually worked as a solution. Thank you.