# Number of symbols of text file

Tags: php, string, file

I've a text file `text.txt`. How can I count the number of symbols in this file using `php`. I don't know the character encoding in advance. I'm using the following:

```
$fcontent=file_get_content('text.txt');
iconv_strlen($fcontent, 'UTF-8');
```

I'm using the `UTF-8` encoding. How can I count the number of symbols in `text.txt` correct if we don't know anything about the encoding of `fcontent` in advance?

Comment: You can make use of regex, similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593565/regular-expression-for-accurate-word-count-using-javascript just use chars instead of whole words

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample text please:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not know the encoding, you cannot correctly count characters represented by it.

You could try to *guess* the encoding by going through a list of candidates with `mb_check_encoding` (or use `mb_detect_encoding`, which just does the same thing, but be very clear that it does *not* magically "detect" any encodings). But it's fundamentally impossible to guess an encoding this way with 100% accuracy, so don't expect it to work.

The only real answer is that you need to figure out a way to convey or specify what encoding you're getting.