# trying to find words that begin with a

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing some code to find words in paragraphs that begin with the letter "a". I was wondering if there was a shortcut that I could put inside of a variable. I do know about the startsWith() function but that does not work for what i'm trying to do. Here's what I have so far. I'm trying to use the match method and .innerText to read the paragraphs.

```js
function processText() {
  var totalNumberOfWords = document.getElementById('p')
  var wordsBegginingWithA = 0;
  var wordsEndingWithW = 0;
  var wordsFourLettersLong = 0;
  var hyphenatedWords = 0;

}
```

```html
<p><button onClick="processText();">Process</button></p>
<p id="data"></p>
<p>The thousand injuries of Fortunato I had borne as I best could; but when he ventured upon insult, I vowed revenge. You, who so well know the nature of my soul, will not suppose, however, that I gave utterance to a threat.
  <span style='font-style:italic;'>At
            length</span> I would be avenged; this was a point definitely settled--but the very definitiveness with which it was resolved precluded the idea of risk. I must not only punish, but punish with impunity. A wrong is unredressed when retribution
  overtakes its redresser. It is equally unredressed when the avenger fails to make himself felt as such to him who has done the wrong.</p>
```

Comment: We are going to need some code in order to help you...

Comment: changed it. Lmk if you need any more code

Comment: Could you also supply the related paragraph

Comment: It is very long, about 300 lines. Can I give one of the paragraphs and the button that I have linked to the function?

Comment: Just give a small portion of the paragraph that has all the needed content.

Comment: Done, also is there a shortcut to identify code on stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the inner text of the p element - split it at the spaces to get the words - pass the words through a function to see if the first letter is "a" and if so, increment a count.

```js
processText();


function processText() {
  var p = document.querySelector('p').innerText; 
  var totalWords = p.split(' ');
  var wordsBegginingWithA = 0;

  totalWords.forEach(function(word){
    if ( beginsWithA(word) ) {
       wordsBegginingWithA++
     };
   })
        
  console.log(wordsBegginingWithA); // gives 5
}
        
        
 function beginsWithA(word){
   return word.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'a';
 }
```

```html
<p>Apples and oranges are fruit while red and blue are colors</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: 
`[variablename].match(`[`/(?<!\w)a\w*/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/aDSPkU/1)`)!=null? a.match(/(?<!\w)a\w*/ig).length:0;`  to detect what words starting with what letter (in example it was a).

And: 
`[variablename].match(`[`/\S+/g`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4593637/3654837)`)!=null? a.match(/\S+/g).length:0;` 
to detect word count.

```js
function processText() {
    var a = document.getElementById('p').innerText;
    var b = a.match(/(?<!\w)a\w*/ig)!=null? a.match(/(?<!\w)a\w*/ig).length:0;
    var word= a.match(/\S+/g)!=null? a.match(/\S+/g).length:0; 
    console.log('Text: ',a,'\nA starting word: ', b, '\nWord count: ',word);

}

processText();
```

```html
<span id="p">Apple is super delicious. An ant is as good as my cat which favors a pear than fish. I'm going to test them all at once.</span>
```

Explanation: `.match` would return all value which matches the expression given.
Notice that I also used [`conditional (ternary) operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to detect whether or not the Regex will return a null value if no match were returned. If it's returning null then it would result in 0 (`:0`) if it's returning another value than null then it would return the count (`.length`).

More info related to Regular expression: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: what is the "<span>" element? Sorry I am pretty new to coding.

Comment: What if the first word starts with `a`? Then `a.match(/(\ba\S+\b)/ig).length;` do not works

Comment: @Mukyuu covered all scenarios.. Great answer!

Comment: It's showing an error that says it's returning as null.

Comment: @JohnKosmalski How is your use case?

Comment: What is a use case? Like a switch statement?

Comment: No. I mean how do you use it so it would return the null? Since I've added the conditional statement if it's null would return 0.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function processText() {
    let pp = document.getElementById('root')
    console.log(pp.innerHTML.match(/(?<!\w)a\w*/g))
    return pp.innerHTML.match(/(?<!\w)a\w*/g);
}
processText()
```

```html
<p id='root'>this is a apple</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the result of `indexOf`, 0 is the equivalent to `startsWith`

```
  var str = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  var keyword = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var n = str.indexOf(keyword);`
```

Working sample in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brwm2tzg/).

HTH