# get number then get n names and count each word vowel char JS

Tags: javascript

The goal is to get a number n from the user then get n words from the user and show each word vowel char count in the console. But it doesn't get the counts correct.  #JS #vowel

```
let n = prompt('Enter the number:');
let wordList = [];
let vowelCounter = [];
let stringWordList = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    wordList.push(prompt((i + 1) + 'Word #'))
}
debugger
function getVowels(str) {
    var m = str.toString().match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    return m === null ? 0 : m.length;
};
/*function vowelCount(str) {
    return str.toString().replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, "").length;*/
};
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    stringWordList = wordList[i].toString
    vowelCounter.push(getVowels(stringWordList));
    console.log(wordList[i] + ':' + vowelCounter[i]);
}
```

Comment: `get a number n from the user then get n words from the user` Hi!  Why would you ask for the number AND the words when there's a way to count the words too, avoiding two inputs.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20255912/3196753.  Otherwise, you're relying on the user to enter two values correctly, which could cause more bugs down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the carrot symbol from the regex and try:

```js
function getVowels(str) {
    var m = str.toString().match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    return m === null ? 0 : m.length;
};

console.log(getVowels("testme123"));
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @sinajabbarpour The example has been updated so you can run it here. It works without issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

After removing your carrot symbol, you need to clean a bit your code (was not running on JSFIDDLE):

```js
let n = prompt('Enter the number:');
let wordList = [];
let vowelCounter = [];
let stringWordList = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    wordList.push(prompt((i + 1) + 'Word #'))
}
//debugger
function getVowels(myString) {
    var m = myString.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    return m === null ? 0 : m.length;
}
/*function vowelCount(str) {
    return str.toString().replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, "").length;*/
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    stringWordList = wordList[i].toString();
    vowelCounter.push(getVowels(stringWordList));
    console.log(wordList[i] + ':' + vowelCounter[i]);
}
```